# Check if a user has logged in SharePoint or not?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Is there a way we can track when a user logged in SharePoint last time. 
Any rest apis that track user activity.

Answer (score 0):

In Office 365, we can use the default Reports in Admin Center([Office 365 Reports in the Admin Center - SharePoint activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/activity-reports/sharepoint-activity?redirectSourcePath=%252fclient%252fSharePoint-activity-a91c958f-1279-499d-9959-12f0de08dc8f&view=o365-worldwide)) to achieve it. Or we can also use PowerShell to [export all Office 365 user last logon date to CSV file](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Export-Office-365-Users-ae3463f2).

In SharePoint on-premise, we can also use PowerShell with server code to achieve it.

**Reference**: [Find the Last Login Time of a SharePoint User from AD with PowerShell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/01/find-last-login-time-of-sharepoint-user.html)

Comment: I need to do in SharePoint 2013 from the client side, Rest API or CSOM.

Comment: There is not a client side API to achieve it, as a workaround, we can create a custom REST API in the server, then consume the custom REST API from the client side.